# Нужна формула периметра ромба

Tags: математика, геометрия

Подскажите, формулу периметра ромба, если известно 2 диагонали.

Answer (score 3):

4 * root((a/2)^2 + (b/2)^2)

a и b - диагонали.

Корень из суммы (половин каждой диагонали в квадрате) умножить на 4. Как-то так?

Answer (score 3):

D1 - первая диагональ

D2 - вторая диагональ

По теореме Пифагора находим длину одной стороны и умножаем на 4.

`sqrt(((D1 / 2) ^ 2 + (D2 / 2) ^ 2)) * 4`

---

Как было замечено тов. [alexlz](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/352/alexlz) ниже, формула сокращается до:

`sqrt(D1 ^ 2 + D2 ^ 2) * 2`

Comment: Только вот деления и умножения можно смело заменить на умножение на два (элементарное приведение) `2 * sqrt(D1^2+D2^2)`

Comment: тоже правильно